# How to view the managed properties of a particular item?

Tags: search, managed-property

I am able to view the managed properties in the search schema, but what I want to know is how to view the managed properties' values for a particular item?

I am a newbie here and I would really appreciate you people's help.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is via a REST call for search.

A simple way to do this with some additional "help" is the Search Query Tool

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool

Search for the item and click on the result for a single item after connecting to your farm (Any Sitecollection as target will do) this will open up a new window to show all managed Properties in a simple grid

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know if this will only show the out of the box managed properties or all the managed properties (custom ones also)?

Comment: It will show all managed properties.

Comment: The initial result will only show a smaller (default) subset of them. But when you click on the item to open the detail window you will get them all.